# Swift Convert array of PHAsset to array of URL

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I have an array of `PHAssets`, so I want to convert it to array of `URL`

```
func getURL(ofPhotoWith mPhasset: PHAsset, completionHandler : @escaping ((_ responseURL : URL?) -> Void)) {
    let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
    options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
        return true
    }
    mPhasset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
        completionHandler(contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageURL)
    })
}


func getUrlsFromPHAssets(assets:[PHAsset], completion: @escaping ((_ urls:[URL]) -> ())){
    var arrUrl:[URL] = []
    for asset in assets {
        self.getURL(ofPhotoWith: asset) { (url) in
            arrUrl.append(url!)
        }
    }
    completion(arrUrl)
}
```

I call function below in my main.

```
self.getUrlsFromPHAssets(assets: assets, completion: { (urls) in
            print(urls)
})
```

So,in function `getUrlsFromPHAssets`, how can I wait the loop of appending urls to array of urls finish and then return it.

> Update function `getUrlsFromPHAssets`:

```
func getUrlsFromPHAssets(assets:[PHAsset], completion: @escaping ((_ urls:[URL]) -> ())){
    var arrUrl:[URL] = []
    var index:Int = 0
    for asset in assets {
        self.getURL(ofPhotoWith: asset, completionHandler: { (url) in
            arrUrl.append(url!)
            if index == assets.count - 1 {
                completion(arrUrl)
            }
            index = index + 1
        })
    }
}
```

After updating function, the result seem to be ok, but I'm not sure that it'll correct anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second function, you are using a `for` loop to execute a bunch of asynchronous functions. Whenever you have multiple asynchronous functions whose completions all depend on one another like this, you probably want a `DispatchGroup`. This object can call `enter()` to indicate an async block is starting, and `leave()` once the async block is done.

```
func getUrlsFromPHAssets(assets: [PHAsset], completion: @escaping ((_ urls:[URL]) -> ())) {
    var array: [URL] = []
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for asset in assets {
        group.enter()
        self.getURL(ofPhotoWith: asset) { (url) in
            // I changed this from force unwrapping.
            // Seems like it's totally possible to get back a nil URL,
            // in which case, you don't want to crash
            if let url = url {
                array.append(url)
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    // This closure will be called once group.leave() is called
    // for every asset in the above for loop
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(array)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just update my function, the result seem to be ok. but I'm not sure. Can you check it?

Comment: Well... no. Your updated code won't work at all. You're trying to hack around the fact that it's an asynchronous function.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.